Lua Scripts in Redis
In the document it is mentioned that "While executing the script, all server activities are blocked during its entire runtime."

Does this mean that while executing the Lua Script in Redis all
other operations like commands from clients (Redis Clients from
.NET) are also blocked?

If there is any RedLock(using RedLock.net) created on a specific Key and if an Lua
Script is triggered which also modifies the same Key,how this will have impact?

Since Functions and Triggers are not moved to GA are there any alternatives in Redis to
execute certain Lua Script at a set frequency



In which document?  The answer depends on how the web server itself is architected.  If handlers are called by the same thread that reads socket requests, then it can't get back to check for more data until your handler is complete.


The Redis instance on which the script is running will not be able to execute any other commands, this includes those coming from other clients (e.g. your .NET Redis Client), the only override for this would be something like SCRIPT KILL
RedLock is a design pattern meant to provide distributed locking for your Redis instance. Treat it the same way you'd treat any other semaphore, once acquired, the critical code (or in this case keys) shouldn't be touched by any client that hasn't acquired them. If you break that convention you are liable to encounter race conditions.
Not internally to Redis no, but you can always run a cron job to execute a script or function periodically.

